# How to use a variable with a mailto email address recepient

Tags: html, forms, email, mailto

I am trying to have a mailto form that will send text entered to an email address entered above. The email form is the variable "to". how could I have it so when the form is up, someone enters their email the variable to is assigned that email. Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance
-Ben

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--chtml include "//webinfo/incs/header.inc"-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <title>Mailto Variable</title>
    <link href="/webinfo/webinfo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Mailto Basic Demo</h1>

    <form action="basic.mailto" method="post">
       <tr>
            <td>Your E-mail Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="to" value="" size="55" /></td>
        </tr>
       <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sendername" value="" size="55" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Comments:</td>
            <td><textarea name="comments" rows="15" cols="55">

</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send Comment" />
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Comment" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <!--chtml include "//webinfo/incs/footer.inc"-->
    </body>

</html>

Here is basic.mailto

    <to>"to"</to>
```

Comment: I am not even sure what you are trying to do? How do you intend to send the mail? What is happening after you've closed the HTML-tag?

Comment: what are you trying to do? do you want to know how to access the post variables when you submit the form?

Comment: Is this a publicly accessible form? Beware if the recipient of an email is provided by the web browser, then bots will use your server to send out spam. This will get your server blacklisted by every major mailserver in the world, making it impossible for you to send emails without them being deleted before reaching the recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use mailto: to send an email, then your form-tag would have to look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@domain.com">
```

However, using that method is not a very good one. That method relies on the user having a default e-mail client set up, that can be used to send the email through.

Instead, I would suggest that you use a server-side language to post the email. Have a look at PHPs [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for instance.

If you intent to send e-mails, it is also worth looking in to web services like [Postmark](http://www.postmarkapp.com) to make sure that your emails are delivered properly and not getting caught in SPAM-filters. There are a libraries for most server-side languages that you can use if you like to use Postmark: http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-libs.html